# SQL Server convert date to specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

How do I convert the date column to this format:

```
"dateUpdated": "2024-03-20T15:36:56.897Z"
```

If my date in the SQL Server database is such

```
2024-03-20T15:36:56.8970000
```

The best I could find so far is

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 126) as 'Date'
```

But it does not give me that **Z** for a time zone option, which I need to have to have.

My database is an Azure SQL Server instance (if it matters)

Comment: Try `FORMAT` (and don't single quote your alias - thats bad practice - double quote or square bracket it).

Comment: Please try `FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: `2024-03-20T15:36:56.8970000` would appear to be a [`datetime2` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql), which doesn't know anything about time zones. If you want something that's time zone-aware then you're probably wanting the [`datetimeoffset` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Thanks, all.
FORMAT was what I was looking for.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I know.  Type in the db stays datetime2.  I was only concerned for the output format in the result of a select going to the usage system